# Why does some paid software say requires mouse?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I have paid for software through the software center that says a mouse is required but no  mouse is setup, I am running 12.04 on my laptop.

Comment: Could you mention some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a pointer device. You can use a mouse, trackball, trackpad, or similar device to interact with the app. It doesn't absolutely have to be a mouse.

If however, you only have a touchscreen, and no other pointer device, you may find it difficult to use some features of the software.